# how to display particular wordpress post onclick of its title from all of the posts

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to display particular post data in WordPress while clicking on its title. Like I have four post 1, 2, 3 and 4 by default it shows post 1 data and when I click on 2 it should show only post 2 data. I have photo gallery in left side and in right side is the content of the post.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="door">
                <?php query_posts(array('post_type'=>'door_function', 'posts_per_page'=>4, 'order' => 'ASC', 'paged' => $paged,)); ?>
                <?php if(have_posts()) { while(have_posts()) {  the_post(); ?>  
                    <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
                        <span class="door_link"><a href="#<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
                    </div>
                <?php }  }?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php query_posts(array('post_type'=>'door_function', 'posts_per_page'=>4, 'order' => 'ASC', 'paged' => $paged,)); ?>
    <?php if(have_posts()) { while(have_posts()) {  the_post(); ?>
    <div class="door_function" id="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="outer" style="overflow:hidden;">
                    <div id="sync1" class="owl-carousel">
                        <?php  if( have_rows('images') ):
                            while ( have_rows('images') ) : the_row(); ?>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img src="<?php the_sub_field('post_image');?>"/>
                                </div>
                         <?php endwhile;
                            endif;
                        ?>   
                    </div>
                   <div id="sync2" class="owl-carousel">
                    <?php  if( have_rows('images') ):
                        while ( have_rows('images') ) : the_row(); ?>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="<?php the_sub_field('post_image');?>"/>
                            </div>
                     <?php endwhile;
                        endif;
                     ?> 
                   </div>

                 </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-1">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h3><?php the_field('subtitle'); ?> </h3>
                    <h2><?php the_field('title'); ?> </h2>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php the_field('video_link'); ?>">PLAY THE VIDEO</a>
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
    <?php }  }?>
```

I'm new to jquery, please help me out.

Comment: its not clear what you want to accomplice, could you elaborate

Comment: I want to display particular post data while I click on its title. you can see in class door i shown only title of post so when i click on it just show particular post data and other post will be hide

Comment: means if you clicking on Post 1 it will be opened and when you clicking on post 2, it will also open bt post 1 should not be closed. Does it what u mean?

Comment: Not opened. First of all I'm sorry if you didn't get me. I want like tab function when click on it particular post data show only.

Comment: ohkay if i m not wrong.. this may help you. you can use <iframe> or <div> window to open all post in just one window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide all div with class `door_function`  first when any of your titles are clicked then show the currently clicked div. But you are missing the links that will be displayed as tabs or any other way so that user can click on them. I have added jquery code to your code to show hide. You can modify it to your needs.

```
<?php
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="door">
            <?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'door_function', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'order' => 'ASC', 'paged' => $paged,)); ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) {
                while (have_posts()) {
                    the_post(); ?>  
                    <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
                        <span class="door_link"><a href="#<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
                    </div>
                <?php }
            } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'door_function', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'order' => 'ASC', 'paged' => $paged,)); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post(); ?>
        <div class="door_function" id="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="outer" style="overflow:hidden;">
                            <div id="sync1" class="owl-carousel">
                                    <?php if (have_rows('images')):
                                        while (have_rows('images')) : the_row();
                                            ?>
                                        <div class="item">
                                            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('post_image'); ?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php
                                    endwhile;
                                endif;
                                ?>   
                            </div>
                            <div id="sync2" class="owl-carousel">
                                <?php if (have_rows('images')):
                                    while (have_rows('images')) : the_row();
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="item">
                                            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('post_image'); ?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php
                                    endwhile;
                                endif;
                                ?> 
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <h3><?php the_field('subtitle'); ?> </h3>
                        <h2><?php the_field('title'); ?> </h2>
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php the_field('video_link'); ?>">PLAY THE VIDEO</a>
                        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    <?php }
} ?>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.door_function').hide();

    $('.door_function').first().show();

    $(document).on('click', '.door_function', function(){

        $('.door_function').hide();
        $(this).show();
    });
});    
</script>
```

Comment: I used this code but it just hide not showing other post when i clicked on title.

Comment: You need to make separate links outside the div with class `door_function` and do some jquery accordingly